# Help box on the right bleeds over the text on the bottom

Tags: bug, status-declined, design

Especially when the text box gets long, it seems like the help box on the right covers the links on the bottom of the stackoverflow page:

[image]

I guess this isn't a full-on bug, but in my opinion it's a little ugly from a ui perspective and inconvenient from a ux perspective, so just wanted to notify people of that!

Comment: Related on the main meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136849/right-hand-sidebar-covers-the-footer-on-the-ask-question-page-and-markdown-hel